# Show Popup on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Following code, but it is not working.

```
  $('#img').on('click', function () {
        $("#new").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            position: { my: "center", at: "top+350", of: window },
            width: 1000,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Add User Form',
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("_new", "Help")');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Add User": function () {
                    addUserInfo();
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

I have a partial view name `_new` in `Help` Folder Under `Views`.

Can someone guide me too achieve it. I am using MVC4 framework :)

Comment: what is currently happening? what is issue coming?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It is not displayimg anything onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the click to the anchor (`a`) instead of the `img`. The click event will never reach the `img`.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jr7Vf/1/).

Comment: It is doing nothing in fiddle too i guess

Comment: @Richa: Need more help?

Comment: You can use chat if you want to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53946/discussion-between-patrick-hofman-and-richa)